# $sort with least value inside an array mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents in the database. What I would like is to be able to sort the documents by the value of one of its subdocuments that's inside an array. Is this possible to do?

```
{
    name: "Item A",
    subItems: [{
        name: "Subitem 1",
        value: 10
    },
    {
        name: "Subitem 2",
        value: 20
    }]
},
{
    name: "Item B",
    subItems: [{
        name: "Subitem 1",
        value: 5
    },
    {
        name: "Subitem 2",
        value: 60
    }]
}
```

I would like to sort the documents by the value of one of the subitems so that the expected outcome for sorting by ascending would be below (in this case sorting by descending would also give the same result because item B has both lowest and largest value items). I don't really care for the order of the subitems in this query, just the order of the parent documents.

Expected outcome:

```
{
    name: "Item B",
    subItems: [{
        name: "Subitem 1",
        value: 5
    },
    {
        name: "Subitem 2",
        value: 60
    }]
},
{
    name: "Item A",
    subItems: [{
        name: "Subitem 1",
        value: 10
    },
    {
        name: "Subitem 2",
        value: 20
    }]
}
```

I know it will have to use aggregation but no idea how to even start with this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which value you are talking about.

### Scenario 1

If sorting by the array itself, it will use the min/max value if you are sorting ascending/descending. Simply do:

```
db.coll.find({...}).sort({"subItems.value"})
```

There's no way any index can support this sorting.

### Scenario 2

Or, you can specify which element you want to use as sort key:

```
db.coll.find({...}).sort({"subItems.0.value"})
```

This sorting can be supported by:

```
db.coll.createIndex({"subItems.0.value": 1})
```

### Scenario 3

If none of the above is what you wanted, I think you probably mean to filter by some condition and sort by that element. This is possible by using aggregation:

```
db.bar.aggregate([
    {$match: {"subItems.value": {$lte: 10}}}, 
    {$project: {
        subItems: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$subItems",
                as: "item",
                cond: {
                    $lte: ["$$item.value", 10]
                }
            }
        }
    }},
    {$sort: {"subItems.value": -1}}
])
```

The [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) operator essentially filter element by some condition. After that, it's no different than sorting by an array like we did in scenario 1.
In this query the first `$match` can leverage index `{"subItems.value": 1}` while the `$project` and `$sort` is pure CPU work.

Comment: Non of the "Scenerio" is correct. OP needs to `$sort` with minimum value which is inside  the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is simplest solution you can use here.

Use [**`$min`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) aggregation operator to find the lowest value inside the `subItems` array and then `$sort` by with it

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "order": { "$min": "$subItems.value" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "order": 1 }}
])
```